# How to test a capacitive microphone

Tags: microphone

How can I test a mini capacitive microphone?
I have a mini microphone(something used in telephones) and I want to create a circuit to see how it works?
I want to speak to it and see how current or voltage or resistance changes as I speak to it

Comment: do you have an oscilloscope to view the waveforms produced by speech?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Is there any other way to see it

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if you can't use an o-scope?

Answer (score 3):

For most cheap capacitive microphones (which include the built-in amplifier, and this is probably your case, as you call it a "mini microphone used in phones") the circuit below should work. Typical Vcc should be +3.3V or +5V (do you have any documentation of your microphone, stating what is the acceptable power supply voltage?).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa8yKO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Some microphones of this type are polarized because a FET transistor included as a preamp. Usually one of the pin is connected with the outer shell. This is the GND.

Comment: Is there any way to see the output without oscilloscope?

Answer (score 1):

The simple test of electret microphone - is "blow".
Just blow to it and measure the resistance. It should fluctuate near 2kOhm.